# Navigator.push {object} properties?

Tags: navigation, react-native

I am breaking my head down to what properties I have to pass into `Navigator.push({ properties?? })` in my App. I can't find anything online on the React Native website.

Can anyone help me please.. If you can point where I can read those properties would be great.

**UPDATED**

My actual problem was to move from one page to next using `Navigator.push` where I was doing the next:

```
return (
            <React.Navigator
                initialRoute={{name: 'First Page', index: 0, component: MyFirstPage}}

                navigationBar={this.getNavigationBar()}

                 navigator={this.props.navigator}

                renderScene={(route, navigator) => {

                    return (
                    <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>
                      <MyFirstPage
                        title={'MyFirstPage'}
                        navigator={navigator}
                        route={route}
                      />
                    </View>
                    );
                }}

            />
        );
```

Where passing `MyFirstPage` was **wrong** as it will always redirect me to same Component, which in this case is `MyFirstPage`. I had to change it simply (as @nader-dabit showed in his example) to have Component dynamic as:

```
 return (
        <React.Navigator
            initialRoute={{name: 'First Page', index: 0, component: MyFirstPage}}

            navigationBar={this.getNavigationBar()}

             navigator={this.props.navigator}

            renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
                let NextComponent = route.component;

                return (
                <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>
                  <NextComponent
                    title={'MY FIRST PAGE!!'}
                    navigator={navigator}
                    route={route}
                  />
                </View>
                );
            }}

        />
    );
```

Now I can go from Page1 to Page2 etc...

Answer (score 2):

The only one that absolutely has to be there is `component` if you are rendering using the route.component in your renderScene method :

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    component: About
})
```

You could also only pass in the id, and in your renderScene method do a check for something like this:

```
if (routeId === 'Login') {
       return (<Login {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator}/>);  
}
```

But really any properties you would like to set up really depend on your renderScene configuration.

All properties passed to .push are then available on the renderScene `route` property:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    component: About,
    color: 'white',
    name: 'jim'
})

renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if(route.color == 'white') { console.log("WHITE COLOR PASSED TO NAV") }
    if(route.name == 'jim') { alert('JIM ROUTE') }
    return React.createElement(route.component, { ...this.props, ...route.passProps, navigator, route } )
}
```

You can also pass properties to use directly in the route itself by attaching an object. Most of the time you will see this called `passProps` but it could literally be called anything you want:

**Example:**

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  color: 'white',
  component: About,
  id: 1
  name: {
    name: 'Chris'
  },
  path: {
    location: 'Nashville'   
  },
  passProps: {
    someprops: someprops
  }
})
```

Set this up in your `renderScene` method:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    return React.createElement(route.component, { ...this.props, ...route.name, ...route.path, ...route.passProps, navigator, route } )
},
```

And use it like this:

```
var About = React.createClass({
    render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>HEllo from About</Text>
            <Text>These are the props: { this.props.someprops }</Text>
            <Text>MY NAME IS { this.props.name }</Text>
            <Text>MY LOCATION IS { this.props.location }</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
})
```

I've set up most of these examples [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/pZ5ZFw).

https://rnplay.org/apps/pZ5ZFw

Comment: That was it man! ```renderScene(route, navigator) {
    return React.createElement(route.component...``` In my code I had always static component in my code, that's why my router was going to the same page. Thanks! Really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `route`, as such:

```
navigator.push({
  name: 'Scene ' + nextIndex,
  index: nextIndex,
});
```

[Navigator Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html)